VNC Server config - IpClientAdresses
I'm trying to TigerVNC to my Pi Zero 2 but getting "The connection was dropped by the server..." It used to work until recently.
I think I understand the problem:

I've just updated my broadband and my provider has (oddly) gone with the 192.168.178.0/24 subnet for my house.
vnc-x11.log contains the line "Configuration: IpClientAddresses=+192.168.0.0/24,- (Preference)"

I'm therefore assuming RealVNC is blocking my main PC on my house subnet because of this.
If I'm right, can anyone guide me on how to change VNC server config?
I've tried:

command line: sudo vncserver-x11 -service -IpClientAddresses=+192.168.0.0/24
Creating a common.custom file in /etc/vnc/config.d with the single line "IpClientAddresses=+192.168.0.0/16,- "

Neither seems to work. The command doesn't complete, and when I restart the service the log file reports the same and TigerVNC fails.
Now, of course I could change my home subnet back (and that would probably be the quickest and most sensible option) but dammit, surely there must be a way!

If your computers are setup to use DHCP the router should assign addresses on the same subnet. There should be NO need to fiddle with IP addresses. Your question is lacking any detail.

OK, by the law of sod, I find an answer right after posting...
The terminal command did work (sudo vncserver-x11 -service -IpClientAddresses=+192.168.0.0/16) but as a Linux newbie I hadn't initially realised that the disappearing command prompt was VNC running in the foreground and had Ctrl-Ced (D'oh!) out of it.
So, with VNC running from the terminal command, and successfully connecting via TigerVNC it's then possible to change the VNC permitted Clients subnet via the GUI using VNC options then changing the rules under 'connections'.
I still don't know why my common.custom file failed to work, but hey it's all running now.
